# Dequeing Parent Fontawesome Deques Parent Styles

Tags: css, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I'm trying to dequeue fontawesome from a parent theme in my child theme. For this I use the following code:

```
function si_dequeue_child_styles()
{
    wp_dequeue_style('wp-bootstrap-starter-fontawesome-cdn');
    wp_deregister_style('wp-bootstrap-starter-fontawesome-cdn');
}

add_action('wp_print_styles', 'si_dequeue_child_styles', 99);
```

However, this seems to also dequeue the parents theme styles, which I don't want. What could be causing this?

For reference, I'm using the widely know WP Bootstrap Starter theme.

---

**Solution**

I found the cause for my problem. I used the "Child Theme Configurator" plugin to generate my child theme. The plugin put the following code at the top of my functions.php. The plugin decided that `wp-bootstrap-starter-fontawesome-cdn` was relevant for the loading of the themes main CSS (look at the very end of the `wp_enqueue_style` function):

```
if (!function_exists('chld_thm_cfg_parent_css')):
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css()
    {
        wp_enqueue_style('chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'style.css', array('wp-bootstrap-starter-bootstrap-css', 'wp-bootstrap-starter-fontawesome-cdn'));
    }
endif;

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10);
```

Comment: Did you check if their styles require this as a dependency? If so, it cannot be loaded now and hence the result. To avoid this, you can dequeue the parent theme and enqueue it on your own - now without the dependency.

Comment: I found the problem. It was a dependency, as you said, but it wasn't in the parent theme, it was in the child theme (the one place where I didn't look). I'll update my post.

Comment: If possible, please consider writing this as an actual answer (might take 2d, I'm not so sure right now) and then mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I found the cause for my problem. I used the "Child Theme Configurator" plugin to generate my child theme. The plugin put the following code at the top of my functions.php. The plugin decided that `wp-bootstrap-starter-fontawesome-cdn` was relevant for the loading of the themes main CSS (look at the very end of the `wp_enqueue_style` function):

```
if (!function_exists('chld_thm_cfg_parent_css')):
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css()
    {
        wp_enqueue_style('chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'style.css', array('wp-bootstrap-starter-bootstrap-css', 'wp-bootstrap-starter-fontawesome-cdn'));
    }
endif;

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10);
```

In any case, it makes sense to search the entire project for any occurrence of the style being enqueued, even where you don't expect it and look for dependencies.